# is there any downside to using rack server during development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

I want to us the new Pow server for ruby on rails develop coz it seems awesome!

http://pow.cx/

I would imagine the code would reload just like running it on webrick or mongrel. but I'm not sure if there is any downside to using it in development mode.

Comment: For development I don't think Pow will give any problems, besides it's from 37 Signals - the creators of Rails.

Comment: I know it wont give any problems but was wondering if there is a downside..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only downside at the moment is it occasionally hangs for me. Forcing it to quit in Activity Monitor fixes things, but it can be a bit frustrating when it happens. Having said that, I've been using it now for all my development, and love it.